# How to find and print all AWK matches in bash?

Tags: awk, echo

I store in variable a lot of text.

```
text="This is sentence! this is not sentence! This is sentence. this is not sencence."
```

I am looking for sentences by this command:

```
echo $text | awk 'match($0,/([A-Z])([^!?.]*)([!?.])/) { print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }'
```

My outup is:

```
This is sentence!
```

Expected output:

```
This is sentence!
This is sentence.
```

**More samples:**
There are grammatically correct and incorrect sentences in the text. The correct sentence is identified by a capital letter at the beginning and the end character (.?!). I want to print only correct sentences.

```
text="incorrect sentence! this is not sentence! This is sentence. this is not sencence. This is correct sentence."
```

Expected output:

```
This is sentence.
This is correct sentence.
```

I am able to find first match, but not all. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `while()` with the `match()`:

```
$ echo $text | awk '
{
    while(match($0,/([A-Z])([^!?.]*)([!?.])/)) {   # while there are matches
        print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)            # output them
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)               # and move forward
    }
}'
```

Output:

```
This is sentence!
This is sentence.
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ echo "$text" | awk -v RS='[A-Z][^!?.]*[!?.]' 'RT{print RT}'
This is sentence!
This is sentence.
```

or GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ echo "$text" | awk -v FPAT='[A-Z][^!?.]*[!?.]' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}'
This is sentence!
This is sentence.
```

or GNU grep for `-o`:

```
$ echo "$text" | grep -o '[A-Z][^!?.]*[!?.]'
This is sentence!
This is sentence.
```

Only the first of the above will work if a sentence can contain a newline.